# php/curl/gracenote ERROR searchTrack/get releaseDate

Tags: php, curl, gracenote

```
 include("../Vendor/phpGracenote/Gracenote.class.php");

 $clientID = ' my Key ';
 $clientTag = ' my Tag ';
 $api = new Gracenote\WebAPI\GracenoteWebAPI($clientID, $clientTag);
 $userID = $api->register();



 $results = $api->searchTrack("Kings Of Convenience", "Riot On An Empty Street", "Homesick", Gracenote\WebAPI\GracenoteWebAPI::BEST_MATCH_ONLY);

 pr($results);
```

I only get an error:

> cURL returned an error when trying to make the request.
>   Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
>
> exception: code=2003, message=cURL returned an error when trying to
>   make the request., ext=60

I think the problem is, that the i first must register my client information in order to get a userID.

```
 $userID = $api->register();
```

But i get this Error and don't now what i can do...

... in the GracenoteError.class.php:

```
const HTTP_RESPONSE_ERROR      = 2003; // A cURL error that wasn't a timeout or HTTP400 response.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a cURL SSL certificate issue. I resolved the problem by doing following:

1. Go to https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem, copy the whole page and save it as "cacert.pem" in a folder of your choice.
2. Open your php.ini, search for "curl.cainfo" and insert "path\to\your\cacert.pem". (Or simply insert "curl.cainfo = "path\to\your\cacert.pem" if no "curl.cainfo" found.)
3. Restart your server, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Error: Call to undefined function Gracenote\WebAPI\curl_init() 
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\Vendor\phpGracenote\HTTP.class.php 
Line: 29

Comment: @ma-jo-ne what's your PHP version?

Comment: wirth the interactive_console i get:

 <RESPONSES>
 <RESPONSE STATUS="OK">
   <USER>my-id</USER>
 </RESPONSE>
                                                                                
</RESPONSES>

Comment: and in the interactive_console i can do everthing... but in my project now:  exception: code=2003, message=cURL returned an error when trying to make the request., ext=77